# Is there a way to open a jsp file in a js popup

Tags: grails

Is there a way to call a .jsp file in a grails project to open in a JS window.open("filename") popup. I tried just the name of the file which was in my views folder but that didn't work. Is there a particular path I should be using or is there a folder I can store a regular html file that I can load into the popup.

Answer (score 0):

What you certainly want to know is if Grails can handle JSP files? The answer is no, but you should be able to use JSP tags within .gsp files.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3906

Answer (score 0):

A GSP file needs to be 'rendered' by Grails before it is elegible for showing in the browser. I would invoke a Grails controller action that renders the GSP template you want displayed using an Ajax call, and have the result shown as the content of the popup.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of how to do this. I can do the call to the controller which I have setup to render a view but not sure how to render it inside the popup. Right now it just renders into the same page as where I had a link on the previous page before the new render .

Comment: When you say Popup, are you referring to as a modal dialog or a window. Usually popups are small